# Manipulating DateTimeIndex in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Please consider this dataframe with a datetime index, on a 5-minute timeframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00', freq='5min', periods=500)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : np.arange(len(index))}, index = index)

print(df)

                    x
2019-01-01 00:00:00 0
2019-01-01 00:05:00 1
2019-01-01 00:10:00 2
2019-01-01 00:15:00 3
2019-01-01 00:20:00 4
... ...
2019-01-02 17:15:00 495
2019-01-02 17:20:00 496
2019-01-02 17:25:00 497
2019-01-02 17:30:00 498
2019-01-02 17:35:00 499
500 rows × 1 columns
```

**goal:** manipulate the datatime index in such as way that `df.loc[specific_date]` will return data starting from 6 pm of the previous date to 5 pm of `specific_date`. For, example, `df.loc['2019-01-02']` should return data starting from 6 pm of 2019-01-**01** to 5 pm of  2019-01-**02**.

What I tried:

```
dates = df.index.date

data_l = []
for i in range(len(dates)-1):

    night_data = df[df.index.date == dates[i]].between_time('18:00', '23:55')
    day_data =   df[df.index.date == dates[i]].between_time('00:00', '16:55')
    data = pd.concat([night_data , day_data ], axis = 0)
    data.index= data.index.map(lambda x : x.replace(day = dates[i+1].day))
    data_l.append(data)

df_reindexed = pd.concat(data_l, axis =0)
```

Note that the indices are not necessarily regular and some may be missing.

**Problem:** The code works but the data is too large (thousands of dates) and the code takes too long. Is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `df.loc["2019-01-01 18:00":"2019-01-02 17:00"]` doesn't work?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, no, that will return the intended data but with both 2019-1-1 and 2019-1-2 in the indices. I need to get that data by `df.loc['2019-01-02']`

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df.resample('D', origin='2018-12-31 18:00')['x'].sum()
```

out:

```
2018-12-31 18:00:00     23220  <-- 2018-12-31 18:00 ~ 2019-01-01 17:59:59
2019-01-01 18:00:00    101530  <-- 2018-01-01 18:00 ~ 2019-01-02 17:59:59
```

---

I do not think it is reasonable to use `df.loc['2019-01-02']` indexing to get data from **2019-01-01 to 5 pm of 2019-01-02**. I think it is more appropriate to use a date as a parameter to extract data for that time.

get data by using dictionary key(date).

```
dfs = {(k + pd.Timedelta('1day')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'): d for k, d in df.resample('D', origin='2018-12-31 18:00')}
```

dfs

```
{
'2019-01-01':          <--get by dfs['2019-01-01']
                        x
 2019-01-01 00:00:00    0
 2019-01-01 00:05:00    1
 2019-01-01 00:10:00    2
 ...                  ...
 2019-01-01 17:45:00  213
 2019-01-01 17:50:00  214
 2019-01-01 17:55:00  215
 
 [216 rows x 1 columns],
 '2019-01-02':         <--get by dfs['2019-01-02']
                      x
 2019-01-01 18:00:00  216
 2019-01-01 18:05:00  217
 2019-01-01 18:10:00  218
 ...                  ...
 2019-01-02 17:25:00  497
 2019-01-02 17:30:00  498
 2019-01-02 17:35:00  499
 
 [284 rows x 1 columns]}
```

you can select 18:00:00 ~ 17:55:55 data by key(date)

or use `shift`

```
out = df.shift(freq='6h').loc['2019-01-01'].shift(freq='-6h')
```

out:

```
                    x
2019-01-01 00:00:00 0
2019-01-01 00:05:00 1
2019-01-01 00:10:00 2
... ...
2019-01-01 17:45:00 213
2019-01-01 17:50:00 214
2019-01-01 17:55:00 215
216 rows × 1 columns
```

use various indexing or slicing in `loc` indexer

Comment: I'm not looking to resample the 5-min data as daily. The resample in my code was just to produce the list of dates from the 5-min data